# Why would a const local array/struct ever not be static in c?

Tags: c, embedded

I'm programming for embedded systems where FLASH storage space and RAM usage are both a concern.

According to the c11 Standard section 6.2.4:

> An object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without the storage-class specifier `static` has *automatic storage duration* ... The initial value of the object is indeterminate. If an
>   initialization is specified for the object, it is performed each time the declaration or compound literal is reached in the execution of the block

If I understand correctly that means in function like so:

```
static void func(void){
   const struct MyStruct j={5,6,7,8};
   const char k[]="long string of some sort";
   /*...some code...*/
}
```

`j` and `k` are required to be (re)initialized upon entering the function, which would mean that the storage location of both j and k must be placed in RAM and initialized from a data section in FLASH with something like memcpy. This means that it's using resources both in RAM and FLASH. Compared to something like:

```
static void func(void){
   static const struct MyStruct j={5,6,7,8};
   static const char k[]="long string of some sort";
   /*...some code...*/
}
```

Where now `j` and `k` are only initialized once and can be referenced directly from FLASH and not copied over to RAM.

Is there ever any benefit to not declaring your (bigger than register size) `const`s as `static`?

Basically, I want to know if I should always be declaring my `const`s as `static` or if there would be a reason not to do so.

Comment: There is no stack in the C standard. Did you check the machine code if compiled with optimisations enabled?

Comment: Adding `static` is a micro-optimization really.

Comment: @Olaf I added some quotes from the C standard and cleaned up my terminology. I did check the (optimized) machine code, and indeed without the `static` modifier my `const`s were being initialized onto the stack with a call to memcpy, but with `static` they were just being directly referenced from FLASH.

Comment: @Rick: Well, it **could** have generated the same code on modern platforms. On AVR or PIC it would cause problems, though. It all depends on the actual code, that's why we need a [mcve] and all necessary information.

Comment: @M.M: It cannot do harm, but omitting it can result in massive overhead for copying. On a PC it might be a nuissance, but on a MCU it can mess up the whole timing.

Comment: @Rick: Be it optimised or not, use the correct sporage class specifier. In general adding `static` will not do harm on modern platforms, but can avoid a lot of problems.

Comment: @Olaf Could you expand on `static` not doing harm into an answer?

Comment: @Rick: No. You should read what the `static` storage class specifier means. Then decide what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I did some experiments with it, this is the code:

```
extern void other_call (int);
extern void other_call2 (const char *);

void test ()
{
    const int var = 32;
    const char * const var2 = "this is a string";
    int var3;

    other_call (var);
    var3 = var * 10;
    other_call2 (var2);
    other_call (var3);
}
```

Then I built it with:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -std=gnu99 -O0 -fno-common -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fno-builtin -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections "-Wa,-adhln=test.s" -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -specs=redlib.specs -MMD -MP "../src/test.c"
```

And got this assembly on the `const` initialization:

```
  42 0004 00AF          add r7, sp, #0
   6:../src/test.c ****     const int var = 32;
  44                    .loc 1 6 0
  45 0006 2023          movs    r3, #32
  46 0008 FB60          str r3, [r7, #12]
   7:../src/test.c ****     const char * var2 = "this is a string";
  47                    .loc 1 7 0
  48 000a 0C4B          ldr r3, .L2
  49 000c BB60          str r3, [r7, #8]
```

The compiler loaded the const value 32 to R3 then stored in RAM to the STACK (R7 were loaded with SP).
To the string `var2` the compiler will do the same it did with the cosntant number, except that instead it will use .L2, that is a place holder for the string address.

Note that it did wrote the variables to the STACK while it wasn't necessary, since they are const and won't be changed.

Now enabling optimization with `-O3:

```
   6:../src/test.c ****     const int var = 32;
   7:../src/test.c ****     const char * var2 = "this is a string";
   8:../src/test.c ****     int var3;
   9:../src/test.c **** 
  10:../src/test.c ****     other_call (var);
  37                    .loc 1 10 0
  38 0002 2020          movs    r0, #32
  39 0004 FFF7FEFF      bl  other_call
  40                .LVL1:
  11:../src/test.c ****     var3 = var * 10;
  12:../src/test.c ****     other_call2 (var2);
  41                    .loc 1 12 0
  42 0008 0348          ldr r0, .L2
  43 000a FFF7FEFF      bl  other_call2
```

Note that there's no STACK operation involved. It load constants right to registers and jump to functions where they're used. Even var3 were optimized out.

Lets see what happen with no `const` qualifier? Well, I need not to post any assembly because it was no different. At the proposed code the `const` qualifiers yield no changes in the generated assembly. Even on optmization `-O0` compiler will still alloc STACK for the const variables. If you really want to enforce the compiler to avoid STACK, enable optimizations. I've also tested with `#define` instead of `const` and it still used the STACK on `-O0`.

Now, turning the variable `static`, the compiler did what it was supposed to do, it stored variables in RAM, and loaded it to registers before using, but not in `-O3`. With optimizations enabled the compiler simply ignored the `static` for the example. Considering variables were only read and never written this optimization is correct.

I know it is a single case for a single compiler, but it is representative for most of cases, there must be corner cases where `const` may make a difference that I'm not aware of, but, regarding variable inside functions, if you want optimize use the flags not the `const` nor `static`.

Comment: What about with the `static` qualifier? When I added that is when I saw the msp430 compiler stop utilizing the stack.

Comment: @Rick I edited the answer after doing some experiments with static as well.